# Why am I getting a 404 code to Post to Web API only when I add the correct body?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var uri = new Uri("<SERVER_HOST_NAME>/api/message/picture");

Photo p = new Photo
{
    //set four int variables and read an image into a byte[] from a file
};

var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");


HttpResponseMessage resp = null;
resp = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
//do stuff with the response
```

Here is my routing in my WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}", 
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, id2 = RouteParameter.Optional, id3 = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The function I am trying to access:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("picture")]
public void AddPicture([FromBody] Photo p)
{
    //Call two methods on the photo
}
```

Currently, this is giving me a 404 error. When I change the string content to be a string of random characters it finds the function but returns 500 because the random string can't be converted to a Photo. I have tried using `MultipartContent` and `MultipartFormDataContent` both with the exact same result. I am at a loss because I have other functions that work very similarly to this one and work perfectly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sometimes 404 errors are launched in response to some exceptions in your code. Can you show us some more of the `AddPicture` method?

Comment: @yorodm It never makes it into that code. I have attached Visual Studio to the web service and put a breakpoint in there and it is never hit. If you must know though the code calls two methods, one which saves the image onto the server's hard drive and the other inserts a record into a SQL Database for the photo.

Comment: So if you send the wrong body it fails with a 500 error and the right one fails with a wrong route?

Comment: @yorodm Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Would you be willing to put this in a simple project that reproduces it and upload?  I have a feeling it's unanswerable from the details you've sent.

Comment: Ok, if you're sending the wrong and right parameter to the same route, you should hit the function with the debugger both times. Can you update your question to include the example that fails with error 500?

Comment: Did you check the payload being sent to the API ? it it's too large then also you will get such error. Try with less payload size  and see if you still have problem.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I tried it with a 100x100 image instead of an 800x800 one and that seems to be the problem. I will do some research into how I can send bigger images. Thanks

Comment: When you get internal server error, can you tell us which line of code gets that error? Is it hitting your controller code when you get the error?